# How to merge two UIImage object in Objective-C in iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios, merge, uiimage

I am developing an iPhone Application, and I want to merge two UIImages (leftImage and rightImage). Can anyone suggest how to do that without having lines in between them ?

I am currently doing this :

```
- (UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)first withImage:(UIImage*)second
{
    // get size of the first image
    CGImageRef firstImageRef = first.CGImage;
    CGFloat firstWidth = CGImageGetWidth(firstImageRef);
    CGFloat firstHeight = CGImageGetHeight(firstImageRef);

    // get size of the second image
    CGImageRef secondImageRef = second.CGImage;
    CGFloat secondWidth = CGImageGetWidth(secondImageRef);
    CGFloat secondHeight = CGImageGetHeight(secondImageRef);

    // build merged size
    CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake((firstWidth+secondWidth), MAX(firstHeight, secondHeight));

    // capture image context ref
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mergedSize);

    //Draw images onto the context
    [first drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstWidth, firstHeight)];
    //[second drawInRect:CGRectMake(firstWidth, 0, secondWidth, secondHeight)];
    [second drawInRect:CGRectMake(firstWidth, 0, secondWidth, secondHeight) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    // assign context to new UIImage
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // end context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;

}
```

But it creates a small line between the two images. I don't want this separator, just like how [Splitcam](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splitcam/id428262754?mt=8) does it.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have the edges overlap by one pixel.

```
[second drawInRect:CGRectMake(firstWidth-1, 0, secondWidth, secondHeight) 
   blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
```